# How to prevent my jQuery textarea Focus event from firing repeatedly for ulimted times in a row

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I have something like the basic JavaScript jQuery code below that is only called once in my project code however it alerts 100+ times when my textarea attached to the event is focused by clicking my mouse cursor into it!

```
projectTaskModal.cache.$cmtTextarea.on('focus', function() {
    alert('ON FOCUS EVENT');
});
```

My goal is to fire this event 1 time as it is used to simply add a CSS class and a few other tasks which are then removed after my Form is posted.  A form is posted with an AJAX request and then it is ready for the next `Focus` action to trigger the event again.  However as mentioned it fires 100+ times each time I give it focus!  Not good, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would be better of with a flag. Try this.

```
var isEventTriggered = false;
projectTaskModal.cache.$cmtTextarea.on('focus', function () {
    if (!isEventTriggered) {
        alert('ON FOCUS EVENT');
        isEventTriggered = true;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is actually a good idea as it helps me in some other areas of my app too!  I have seperate functions for `expanding` and collapsing` of the form since it perfomrs about 5 actions in each case and is called from a few locations.  So having the flag var as a variable in my app `projectTaskModal.isTaskCommentFormExpanded`  starting out as false like you mention and then true/false it;s value in my 2  mentioned functions works great and also addresses an issue where it would remain open if a modal window was closed before closing it

Answer (score 0):

have you looked at [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/)

try

```
projectTaskModal.cache.$cmtTextarea.one('focus', function() {
    alert('ON FOCUS EVENT');
});
```

and you might need to attached it back after Form is posted.